# Understanding trains with literal values in J

Tags: j

I'm sure this is obvious but I'm a little unclear about it. Suppose I wanted to make a function do something like `f(x) = 3x+1`. Knowing the rule for forks, I expect to see something like this: `[: 1&+ 3&*` which is not *that* beautiful to me, but I guess is nicer looking that `(1&+) @: (3&*)` with the extra parentheses. Instead, if I query with `13:` I get this:

```
   13 : '1+3*y'
1 + 3 * ]
```

Way more beautiful, but I don't understand how it is possible. `]` is  the identity function, `*` and `+` are doing their usual thing, but how are the literals working here? Why is J not attempting to "call" 1 and 3 with arguments as if they are functions? I notice that this continues to do the right thing if I replace any of the constants with `[` or `]`, so I think it is interpreting this as a train of some kind, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When J was first described, forks were all verbs `(V V V)`, but then it was decided to let nouns be in the left tine position and return their face value. So `(N V V)` is seen as a fork as well. In some older code you can see the left tine of the fork show up as a 'verbified' noun such as `1:` or `'a'"_` which act as verbs that return their face value when given any argument.

`(N V V)` configuration is described in the dictionary as "The train `N g h` (a noun followed by two verbs) is equivalent to `N"_ g h` ." http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dictf.htm